# method definition of javascript class not working - react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I'm working with React. And want to define a class. I try to define a method for the class but the function can't be found in class object.

Here is my class definition:

[image: class definition]

Here's babel config file, I'm not sure if I miss anything.

[image: babel config file]

Here the console.log

[image]

I'm not sure what is the keyword to search for this issue. I tried google it but can't find the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by saying (function can't be found)? How did you test that?

Comment: I new an instance of class and log it to the console. It doesn't have the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bind the method on it in the constructor for that component. If this line is added to the constructor, all will work as expected:

```
this.dummy= this.dummy.bind(this);
```

Comment: this works. but can we make it bind automatically? without adding this line into the constructor?

Comment: nope, you have to bind it yourself. Also, read this official doc about why arrow function works as it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: ohh, since I found another project and it works fine without binding anything, although thanks

Comment: unfortunely you cant, you are  better off using the arrow function, the arrow function doesn't have  the 'this' context, the this context in an arrow method/function is inherited from the parent's scope, and this is called lexical scope. This makes arrow functions to be a great choice in some scenarios but a very bad one in others